# How to uncompress a .Z file

Tags: r

I wish to use R (version 3.2.2) to read a number of files compressed as `.Z` files.  I understand that `uncompress()` has been removed in recent versions. I'd appreciate very much if anyone could let me know how I might be able to use R to **uncompress a .Z file**.

Comment: what OS are you using? You may need to do this by calling another tool using `system()` ...  https://kb.iu.edu/d/abck , http://superuser.com/questions/190053/universal-command-line-unarchiving-tool-on-a-mac

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm using Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that I'm late to the question, but I was looking around to see if there was any better suggestions than what we're doing when I found your question. As Ben suggested, calling another tool is probably your best bet for Windows, Linux and OS X can handle a .Z file natively.

Here's an example of a function (not written by me, Ivan Hanigan wrote it, but I've used it so I know it works) in an R package that checks for the OS, then looks for 7Zip if the OS is Windows.

https://github.com/swish-climate-impact-assessment/awaptools/blob/master/R/ZipFunctions.R

```
################################################################
# name:ZipFunctions.R
uncompress_linux <- function(filename)
  {
    print(filename)
    system(sprintf('uncompress %s',filename))
  }

# tries to find 7 zip exe
ExecutableFileName7Zip <- function()
{
  executableName <- "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"

  if(file.exists(executableName))
  {
    return (executableName)
  }

  #other executable file names and ideas go here ...
  stop("failed to find 7zip")
}

# simple function to extract 7zip file
# need to have 7zip installed
Decompress7Zip <- function(zipFileName, outputDirectory, delete)
{
  executableName <- ExecutableFileName7Zip()

#   fileName = GetFileName(zipFileName)
#   fileName = PathCombine(outputDirectory, fileName)


#   if(file.exists(fileName))
#   {
#     unlink(zipFileName);
#   }

  arguments <- paste(sep="",
                    "e ",
                    "\"", zipFileName, "\" ",
                    "\"-o", outputDirectory, "\" ",
    "")

  print( arguments)

  RunProcess(executableName, arguments)

  if(delete)
  {
    unlink(zipFileName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. This was also what I did then with my work. I guess it, though may not be the only, but was probably the most effective way for R to deal with .Z file on Windows. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install the last-archived version.  (Note that `uncompress` is an *archived package*, not a function that used to exist in base R that has been deprecated/removed ...).  You will need to have appropriate development tools (C compiler, make) installed on your computer [e.g. see point #2 [here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/README.md)].

```
library("devtools")
install_version("uncompress","1.34")
```

This installs cleanly for me with a development version of R, but I haven't actually tried it on any `.Z` files, as I don't have them lying around.

Comment: Thanks Ben. This does not seem to work for me. I've tried to install the development tools as you suggested, but got a message saying "Error: Could not find build tools necessary to build uncompress".