# How to uncompressed .Z files in R with winzip

Tags: r, winzip

I am new to R and have not been able to find anything in particular to uncompress a .z file in R.

I have a file *.z that I would like to uncompress and read into R. Ideally, I would like to delete the extracted file, once its loaded into R (maintain the .z file)

I have winzip installed and looking into using the "system" function to do the extraction, but I am having trouble.

How do I ensure, winzip executable is on my path? I cannot get this function to work.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the `unzip` function that comes with R (`?unzip` for the manual page).

Comment: I have, it does not work for .z files.

Comment: Does these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35755143/how-to-uncompress-a-z-file or https://rpubs.com/otienodominic/398952